# Show message while Rendering View in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, rendering

In my WPF application, I have a view which show about 300 customer control with data.
The data is already in memory. So no waiting time for data.

It takes time ( min 3 Second) to do rendering those controls.
Now, I want to show a Message while Rendering.

I tried with  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory but it was not a success.

Any idea?
Thanks.
Ruhul

Comment: Do you really need to show all 300 controls immediately? Perhaps take a look at [virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls).

Comment: i dont really think multi threading is necessary as the data is in memory u just need [Splash-Screen](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36418/WPF-Splash-Screen.aspx) as its 3 sec wait as i will display a wait message